# xamarin.forms: Observablecollection, Listviews in a Chat: When new messages are added to the top, listview moves up, shou

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I am working on a chat in xamarin forms. I use an observable collection to which items are added with a reload adapter. The logic works and all messages are loaded, exepcet that when a message is added (to the top of the list, not the bottom!) the listview always displays that item as the first. But that means, since the reload works "backwards" that the next item is loaded, the listview moves up again, then the next item is loaded and so on. Ofcourse that means that once the first reload is enabled, it will download all items and move the very top of the chat. That ofc is terrible.

Usually, you would add items to the end of an observable collection, and when done that, the listview stays in place, even though items are added. But that behavior isnt happening when added to the top. Or rather it is, which is the problem: every new item added to the top will leave the listview render the top, but since a chat is backwards, the top of the list is always displayed instead of the bottom.

Here is what I did

```
    private async Task ReloadChatMessages(bool scrollToBeginning)
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        isBusy = true;

        //reset List, cause we only want our new messages on here
        unsortedMessages = new List<ChatType>();

        // keep track of download iterations, skipping the first
        if (result.Count != 0)
            amountOfDownloads++;

        if(amountOfDownloads * Constants.NUMBEROFIADSTOLOADATONCECHAT >= totalNumberOfMessagesAvailable)
        {
            // end reached
            listview_AllChats.ItemAppearing -= Handle_ItemAppearing;
            endReached = true; 
            //load last remaining messages
            int amountOfRemainingMSGs = (amountOfDownloads * Constants.NUMBEROFIADSTOLOADATONCECHAT) - totalNumberOfMessagesAvailable;

            //final load
            unsortedMessages = await Chats.GetAllChats(uniqueChatID, 0, amountOfRemainingMSGs);
                
        }
        else // regular reload 
        {
            // download messages in reverse order 
            unsortedMessages = await Chats.GetAllChats(uniqueChatID,
                (totalNumberOfMessagesAvailable - (Constants.NUMBEROFIADSTOLOADATONCECHAT * amountOfDownloads)),
                Constants.NUMBEROFIADSTOLOADATONCECHAT);
        }





        // since we insert on loads after second we need to reverse list first 
        if (result.Count >= Constants.NUMBEROFIADSTOLOADATONCECHAT)
            unsortedMessages.Reverse();

        //add to all chats, so we are always up to speed with all messages
        allChats.AddRange(unsortedMessages);

        // format message to our visible chat type
        for (int i = 0; i < unsortedMessages.Count; i++)
        {
            if (result.Count < Constants.NUMBEROFIADSTOLOADATONCECHAT)
                result.Add(FormattedChatMessage(unsortedMessages[i]));
            else
            {
                result.Insert(0, FormattedChatMessage(unsortedMessages[i]));

            }
        }


        //traverse list backwards and add number to messsage
        int counter = result.Count; 
        for(int i = totalNumberOfMessagesAvailable; i > (totalNumberOfMessagesAvailable-result.Count); i--)
        {
            result[counter-1].numberOfMessage = i;
            counter--;
        }

        isBusy = false;


        // add to chatview if not already added 
        if (listview_AllChats.ItemsSource == null)
            listview_AllChats.ItemsSource = result;


        if(amountOfDownloads < 2 || scrollToBeginning)
        {
            if (result.Count == 0)
                return;

            VisibleChatType target = new VisibleChatType();

            try
            {
                 target = result[result.Count];

            }
            catch
            {
                target = result[result.Count-1];

            }
            try
            {
                listview_AllChats.ScrollTo(target, ScrollToPosition.End, false);

            }
            catch
            {


            }


        }

    }
```

and the reload adpater:

```
   private async void Handle_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = e.Item as VisibleChatType;

                if (isBusy)
                    return;


                //offset important 
                if (item.numberOfMessage  == totalNumberOfMessagesAvailable + 1 - (result.Count))
                {
                    //LoadMore
                    await ReloadChatMessages(false);
                }
            }
            catch { }



        }
```

Any chance you guys could know how I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to after the reload happend:

listview_AllChats.ScrollTo(item, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);

fixed it!